# How to drag image half out of bound in android

Tags: android

I am making application , In which I want to drag the image around the screen. Right now all thing is working fine , but if user keep swiping left to right the image would go far further into right. Which I do not want to do so .

What I want is that the image should not go out half of its width of bound. I mean image view should go only half out side of view/bound. I want it go half out side of bound in every coordinates I mean to left, right , top and bottom. It should not disappear. For this I am using touch listener. Right now I am capable of doing rotation , zooming and dragging (though its going out of bound)

So now i want it should not go out of bound , here is a code which I am using :

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    //  ImageView view = (ImageView) v;


    //view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    float scale;

    // Dump touch event to log
    dumpEvent(event);

   // Handle touch events here...


    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v;

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mode = DRAG;
            lastEvent = null;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDistance = spacing(event);
            if (oldDistance > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
                                lastEvent = new float[4];
            lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
            lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
            lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
            lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
            d = rotation(event);

            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            lastEvent = null;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                float newX = event.getX() - start.x;
                float newY = event.getY() - start.y;
                if ( newX <= 0-(imageView.getDrawable()
                       .getIntrinsicWidth() )){

                    Log.v("Bounds", "0-drawable width");
                    break;

                }else if (newX >= screenWidth-(imageView.getDrawable()
                        .getIntrinsicWidth())){

                    Log.v("Bounds", "screen wdith-drawable width");
                    break;

                }else if(newY <= 0-(imageView.getDrawable()
                       .getIntrinsicHeight())){

                    Log.v("Bounds", "Y 0-drawable width");
                    break;


                }else if(newY >= (screenHeight-imageView.getDrawable()
                      .getIntrinsicHeight()) ) {

                    Log.v("Bounds", "y Screen-drawable width");
                    break;


                }



                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(newX, newY);




            } else if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                float newDistance = spacing(event);
                if (newDistance > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    scale = newDistance / oldDistance;
                    float[] values = new float[9];
                    matrix.getValues(values);
                    float currentScale = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                    if (scale * currentScale > MAX_ZOOM)
                        scale = MAX_ZOOM / currentScale;
                    else if (scale * currentScale < MIN_ZOOM)
                        scale = MIN_ZOOM / currentScale;
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                }
                if (lastEvent != null) {
                   newRot = rotation(event);
                    float r = newRot - d;
                    /* changes must be

                    float[] values = new float[9];
                    matrix.getValues(values);
                    float tx = values[2];
                    float ty = values[5];
                    float sx = values[0];
                    float xc = (view.getWidth() / 2) * sx;
                    float yc = (view.getHeight() / 2) * sx;
                    matrix.postRotate(r, tx + xc, ty + yc);
                     */
                    float[] values = new float[9];
                    matrix.getValues(values);
                    float tx = values[2];
                    float ty = values[5];
                    float sx = values[0];
                    float xc = (imageView.getWidth() / 2) * sx;
                    float yc = (imageView.getHeight() / 2) * sx;
                    matrix.postRotate(r, tx + xc, ty + yc);
                    //I commented
                    matrix.postRotate(r, imageView.getMeasuredWidth() / 2,
                            imageView.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
               }

            }


            break;
    }

            imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            return true;
    }
```

**Eidt**

> and this is my XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rl_capture">


<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fl_camera">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="content_desc_overlay"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/img_view"

        />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iv_overlay"
        android:src="@drawable/groom01"
        android:scaleType="matrix"

        />

</FrameLayout>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/btn_screenshot"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: don't leave me hanging

Comment: what are you saying ?

Answer (score 0):

Hm. This is a little confusing. Is there some particular reason you're using `intrinsicWidth`/`intrinsicHeight`? These generally do not yield what I think you think they yield ([see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getIntrinsicHeight)). I assume your `imageView` is set up to have `LayoutParams`, and that your gravity isn't set so the origin of the image is at the top left. Here's what I'd do (not tested - tell me if there is an issue):

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (mode == DRAG) {
            float newX = event.getX() - start.x;
            float newY = event.getY() - start.y;

            if ( newX < -imageView.getWidth()/2)){

                Log.v("Bounds", "0-drawable width");
                newX = -imageView.getWidth()/2;

            }else if (newX > screenWidth-(imageView.getWidth()/2)){

                Log.v("Bounds", "screen wdith-drawable width");
                newX = screenWidth-(imageView.getWidth()/2);
            }


            // not else-if: consider the corners!
            if(newY < -imageView.getHeight()/2){

                Log.v("Bounds", "Y 0-drawable width");
                newY = -imageView.getHeight()/2;


            }else if(newY > (screenHeight-imageView.getHeight()/2) ) {

                Log.v("Bounds", "y Screen-drawable width");
                newY = screenHeight-imageView.getHeight()/2;

            }
```

and so on.

Comment: I just wanted to drag image not to much out of bound , but half of the image should go to out of bound and half image must be sticking out in view so that the user know that where is his image?

Comment: I see. I thought you were trying to avoid having the image go offscreen altogether. See my updated answer.

Comment: The origin of the image is at the top left of the image, unless you've explicitly changed it. I'm checking to see if the `newX` and `newY` coordinates are outside the bounds you've established (half the width/height of the image), so at least one quadrant of the image will always be on screen. You had a few bugs in your move logic is all.

Comment: but what If I want to adjust screen at the bottom. And Also it is compulsory to do match parent in height and width?

Comment: its not working , actually I am using your code as it is , can you please provide me the whole procedure as you have written It I think there are further more conditions ? is the code is complete you stated above?

Comment: what isn't working? You've got to be a little more descriptive. I'm trying to help you debug a problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77814/discussion-between-stewjacks-and-stacy-queen).